# How to test public method in Application Module in Oracle ADF?

Tags: java, oracle-adf, jdeveloper

I am working on a project that is based on the Oracle ADF framework. We have an AM (application module) called *TestAM.xml* that has interface *TestAM.java* and implementation class *TestAMImpl.java*.
*TestAMImpl.java* has a public method with a method signature: *String fetchSomething(String id)*

I want to test/debug this method locally by passing the ID parameter, how can I do that? I am trying to run the AM Tester, but that only allows testing of the VOs associated with the AM and not the public methods defined in the AM.

Any leads will be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the ApplicationModuleTester app to test the public methods of an AM.
Run the tester app and right-click on the application module, then select 'show' from the menu.

This will show you the method (in the drow down and its parameters. Set the values and click 'execute' to run the method.

[image]